# Is there a disk defragger for NTFS file systems?

Tags: software-recommendation, defrag

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Defragging NTFS Partitions from Linux](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59007/defragging-ntfs-partitions-from-linux)

I have a couple NTSF disks I'd like to defrag without having to log into my Windows partition. Is there a program for Ubuntu that does disk defraggin?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: [Exact Duplicate](http://askubuntu.com/q/59007/12864)?

Answer (score 0):

> The short answer is no, not really. If it contains a Windows bootable installation, any
>   attempt you make to defragment it in Linux will most likely render it
>   unbootable in Windows. But if is does contain Windows, why not use
>   that to defragment the drive - Windows can be useful for more than
>   playing games. If the drive is used purely for data, then you can
>   severely reduce fragmentation by copying all the data off,
>   reformatting the drive and copying the data back. This requires an
>   NTFS filesystem with full write support, either the commercial Paragon
>   NTFS for Linux application or NTFS-3G, which is included in the Ubuntu
>   repositories. You'll also need the ntfsprogs package.<sup>1</sup>

[Read On](http://www.tuxradar.com/answers/473)

<sup><sup>**1**</sup>Source:[Tuxradar](http://www.tuxradar.com/answers/473)</sup>