# NTFS defrag tool for Ubuntu

Tags: software-recommendation, ntfs, defrag

I am searching for a NTFS defrag tool for Ubuntu and I came across this :
[Defragging NTFS Partitions from Linux](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59007/defragging-ntfs-partitions-from-linux).
I want to know how to install UltraDefrag on Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Reminder :**

> UltraDefrag is a Windows only program and was never tested nor
>   compiled on anything else but Windows. — [UltraDefrag](http://sourceforge.net/p/ultradefrag/discussion/709673/thread/380cf1e6/)

---

There is a `5.0.0AB.7` precompiled version [here](http://tuxera.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=30614) you can use on Ubuntu - you can get it this way :

```
 wget http://jp-andre.pagesperso-orange.fr/tools.zip
 unzip tools.zip
 cd tools/
 ./udefrag
```

---

<sup>Successfully tested on my Ubuntu 15.04.</sup>